# PHP - Checking if string contains some substring FAILS when in LOOP?

Tags: php, string, loops, file-get-contents, strpos

I'm using textarea in this example, but I've also tried with text file uploading, same thing happens...

Basically, this code will return correct result as long as you input **only 1 URL.** As soon as you input another URL, the previous one will be FALSE, no matter the real result. Why?

Code:

```
<?php

if(!$_POST){ 

?>

    <center>

    <h1>Bulk Index Checker v1.0</h1>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <textarea id="list" name="list" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Check 'em!" />
    </form>



    </center>


<?php
}

else{  



$lines = explode("\n", $_POST['list']);

foreach($lines as $site) {

    echo($site); echo("<br>");

    $url='http://www.google.com/search?q=info:'.$site;


    //sleep(3);

        $contents = file_get_contents($url);  // nije do ovoga




        if (strpos($contents,'<h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q='.$site)!=FALSE) {
            echo("YES");
            echo("<br>");
        }
        else{
        echo("NO");
        echo("<br>");
        }
}

}

?>
```

Comment: the site you feed in need to have `<h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q=` in the html

Comment: well, if its indexed in google, it will have that piece of code in the html, and if its not - it wont, and it works fine when testing for a single URL, but as soon as I enter more, it shows false

Comment: yeah because google have search throttled.

Comment: How about setting again $contents to empty before getting another contents from another url?

Answer (score 0):

if `$site` is `www.mysite.de`

if I do a search on google with

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=info:www.mysite.de
```

I get within the answer

```
<h3 class="r"><a href="http://www.mysite.de/"
```

which isn't the same as

```
<h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q='.$site)
```

that expands to

```
<h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q=www.mysite.de"
```

Comment: That's true, and I get the same as you when testing from my own PC; but when I test it by running the script on my host, I get that /url?q= prefix... (i know this because i exported the result into a .txt file and then read it) and it works correctly each time you input a single URL, so it cant be that...

Answer (score 0):

well, first thing to do is printing out htmlentities($contents) when strpos failed so you can check manually why it does not match.

another thing is that google may update the url like appending http:// etc.

also it's not secure to parse html using string functions as you can not trust in sites alsways returning the tags formatted the same way. you should use some library like [domdocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) or [simplehtml](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

It seems that every $site except the last one contained an empty character at the end, so I used the trim() function to get rid of it. Works now, thanks everyone for suggestions.